# Message: Undefined index: rows Filename: tcpdf/tcpdf.php Line Number: 16935

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
if (($dom[$key]['value'] == 'tr')) {
    $dom[$key]['cols'] = 0;
    if ($thead) {
        $dom[$key]['thead'] = true;
    } else {
        $dom[$key]['thead'] = false;

        ++$dom[($dom[$key]['parent'])]['rows'];

        array_push($dom[($dom[$key]['parent'])]['trids'], $key);
    }
}
```

these part shows error.

> Message: array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given

Filename: tcpdf/tcpdf.php

Line Number: 16937

Comment: Message: array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given

Filename: tcpdf/tcpdf.php

Line Number: 16937

Comment: Are you sure `$dom` is multi-dimension array with sub array of `trids`? better to print your `$dom[$key]['parent']` and `$dom[$dom[$key]['parent']]` to see whats in there